# installing percona server on mac OS Symbol not found: _clock_gettime

Tags: mysql, macos, percona

I recently installed `percona-server` through `brew` and got this exception when running `mysql.server start`:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/percona-server/5.7.16-10/bin/mysqld
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, until the patch will be released, manually editing the source code as described in [this pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/8019) will fix this issue.

Then I did:

1) Edit the the source code percona-server.rb  (`vim /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/percona-server.rb`) adding lines following lines at line 76 more or less (after ']' and before '# PAM...')

```
if MacOS.version == "10.11" && MacOS::Xcode.installed? && MacOS::Xcode.version >= "8.0"
  args << "-DHAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME:INTERNAL=0"
end
```

2) Reinstall with modified source:

```
brew reinstall -s percona-server
```

3) Start the server

```
mysql.server start
```

or to start automatically the service at boot time

```
brew services start percona-server
```

For me worked, waiting from pull to be released...

Thanks for @njt1982 which create the pull and share how to do those things and mostly to @ilovezfs which create/share the patch for some packets still useful for those issues!

SR

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there were issues using el capitan and what solved my problem was brew installing percona-server56 as so:

```
brew uninstall percona-server
brew install percona-server56
```

Comment: one of my colleges had the same problem and ended up uninstalling and reinstalling everything related to mySQL that worked for him as well

Comment: I also had to call `brew tap homebrew/versions` first